# How to put an object into an array

Tags: java

How do I put an object into my array? This is my array.

```
public static Player [] playerArray;
Player[] playerArray = new Player [2];
```

player

```
public class Player {
    private String wpm;
    private String mistakes;
    private String time;

    public Player (String nwpm,String nmistakes, String ntime){
        wpm = nwpm;
        mistakes = nmistakes;
        time = ntime;
    }   

    public String getWPM(){
        return wpm;
    }
    public String getMistakes(){
        return mistakes;
    }
    public String getTime(){
        return time;
    }
}
```

I kept getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

whenever I tried to use player. Did I do something wrong? Is there anything else you need?

Edit : adding where the errors happened

```
public void setPlayer1(Player p){
    p1WPM.setText("8");
    p1Mis.setText(p.getMistakes());
    p1Time.setText(p.getTime());
}
```

Comment: at which line the `NullPointerException` occur? You are declaring `playerArray` twice

Comment: show your `main()` method code.Also, why are you declaring `playerArray` twice?

Comment: how you are calling `setPlayer1()`? Add proper code not just snippets which can't be glued together

Comment: Where these objects are created `p1WPM`, `p1Mis`, `p1Time`

Answer (score 2):

For example to add a Player object in array you can do:

```
Player[] playerArray = new Player [2];

//Create new Player object using the defined constructor
p = new Player("a","b","c");

// Assign p to 1st index of array
playerArray[0] = p;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `playerArray` twice which is wrong. Also, you have not shown the code where you are getting the `NullPointerException`.

If you are newbie then try the below code:

```
Player[] playerArray = new Player [2]; //declare array of size 2
Player p1 = new Player("nwpm","nmistakes","ntime"); // first player object
Player p2 = new Player("nwpm","nmistakes","ntime"); // second player object

playerArray[0] = p1; // first player added in the array
playerArray[1] = p2; // second player added in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

`Player[] playerArray = new Player [2];` is creating the array, not the objects.
You should add

```
 playerArray[0] = new Player(param1, param2, param3);
 playerArray[1] = new Player(param1, param2, param3);
```

to have all items have their object

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
  Player a = new Player("a","b","c");
            Player[] playerArray = new Player [2];
            playerArray = new Player[2];
            playerArray[0]=a;
            System.out.println(playerArray[0].getTime()+" "+playerArray[0].getMistakes()+" "+playerArray[0].getWPM());
```

Result:
c b a

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Player[] playerArray = new Player [2];
```

With this statement you are just creating an array of size `2` whose all elements are `null`. But you are not creating elements here.

You have to instantiate each element.

```
for(int i=0; i< playerArray.length;i++)
    playerArray[i] = new Player();//with appropriate constructor
```

If you are trying to perform any operation on `playerArray` like `playerArray[0].mistakes` then get `NullPointerException`. You should initialize each element in the array with a `Player` object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for you.

```
public class Player {
    public static final int SIZE = 2;
    public static Player[] playerArray = new Player[SIZE]; // Creates array of
                                                            // Player of size
                                                            // SIZE

    private String wpm;
    private String mistakes;
    private String time;

    public Player(String wpm, String mistakes, String time) {
        this.wpm = wpm;// this way is more readable
        this.mistakes = mistakes;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getWPM() {
        return wpm;
    }

    public String getMistakes() {
        return mistakes;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * If I wan to add something to the array it has to be object of the
         * array type and I need to create it first
         */

        // Create 2 Player objects
        Player player1 = new Player("p11", "p12", "p13");
        Player player2 = new Player("p21", "p22", "p23");

        // arrays are indexed from 0 to size-1
        playerArray[0] = player1;
        playerArray[1] = player2;

    }
}
```